# Failing to import an image asset with ADB error

Tags: android, user-interface, mobile, flutter, adb

## Background

I am building an Android application using the flutter plugin.  I am attempting to import an image asset but I am getting the following error message

```
adb: failed to install C:\Users\\User1\AndroidStudioProjects\asset_img\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE] 

Error launching application on Android SDK built for x86.
```

## Troubleshooting Steps

Instead of troubleshooting the exception in my application I decided to create a new *Hello World* application and run the same import image function.

Unfortunately, even in this boilerplate application I get the same error.  I suspect the culprit is `[INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]` but I have been unsuccessful trying to solve this.

[Here](https://postimg.cc/1fwLXXfw) is a screenshot of my main.dart file and the exception I am receiving.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: free some memory in your android emulator or run it in a real device.

Comment: Your emulator runs out of storage. Clear some space and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

## Insufficient Storage

This error is very common and does not necessarily mean you are completely out of space.  Try the following:

1. Open your manifest.xml file
2. Check to see if a `android:installLocation` attribute exists in the manifest tag
3. If it doesn't exist, add it and set the value to `preferExternal`

> If the attribute already exists but contains a value other than *preferExternal* simply switch thevalue

So I'm the end it should.look like the following:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.stackoverflow.answer"
      android:installLocation="preferExternal> ... </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

So as Chris & 48n02m41 pointed out I think the problem was that my android device was out of space.

I find this odd considering it's a virtual device and I've only ever run one 'app' on it so far.

To solve this I went onto the AVD Manager and under the 'Actions' drop down menu, I clicked wipe data.

Everything seems to be working fine now - Thanks!